Inconsistent UI Updates with CameraPermissionManager in iOS on Compose Multiplatform
I'm working on a Compose Multiplatform project where I have a screen implemented in commonMain that utilizes a CameraPermissionManager class, which is platform-specific. The screen works fine on Android, but I'm running into issues on iOS where the UI isn't consistently updating based on state changes.
Here's a brief overview of my setup:
In commonMain:
I have a Composable function App() that sets up the UI. It includes a ReadTextScreen composable where the camera preview is started and the detected text is processed.
@Composable
fun App() {
    SosMilkTheme {
        ReadTextScreen()
    }
}

@Composable
private fun ReadTextScreen() {
    val cameraPermissionManager = remember { CameraPermissionManager() }
    val snackBarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    var milkCondition by remember { mutableStateOf<MilkCondition?>(null) }
    var detected by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }

    cameraPermissionManager.RequestCameraPermission(
        onPermissionGranted = {
            Scaffold(
                snackbarHost = {
                    SnackbarHost(hostState = snackBarHostState)
                },
                topBar = { /* ... */ },
                bottomBar = {
                    FooterDetection(
                        title = "Detected Words:",
                        desc = detected,
                    )
                }
            ) { innerPadding ->
                Box {
                    cameraPermissionManager.StartCameraPreview { detectedText ->
                        val res = processDetectedTextUseCase.invoke(detectedText)
                        detected = detectedText
                        milkCondition = res
                    }
                    // other UI elements...
                }
            }
        },
        onPermissionDenied = {
            BodyMedium(text = "Camera access is required.")
        }
    )
}

In iosMain:
My CameraPermissionManager class is responsible for handling camera permissions and starting the camera preview. The text detection uses Apple's Vision framework.
@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
actual class CameraPermissionManager {

    @Composable
    actual fun RequestCameraPermission(
        onPermissionGranted: @Composable () -> Unit,
        onPermissionDenied: @Composable () -> Unit
    ) {
        // Permission handling logic
    }

@OptIn(ExperimentalForeignApi::class)
@Composable
actual fun StartCameraPreview(onTextDetected: (String) -> Unit) {
    val device = AVCaptureDevice.devicesWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        .firstOrNull { device -> (device as AVCaptureDevice).position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack } as? AVCaptureDevice

    if (device == null) {
        println("CameraPermissionManager || No camera found")
        return
    }

    val input = AVCaptureDeviceInput.deviceInputWithDevice(device, null)
    if (input == null) {
        println("CameraPermissionManager || No camera input found")
        return
    }

    val videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

    videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
    videoOutput.videoSettings = mapOf("PixelFormatType" to kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)

    val session = AVCaptureSession()

    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
    session.addInput(input)
    session.addOutput(videoOutput)

    val cameraPreviewLayer = remember { AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session = session) }

    UIKitView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        background = Color.Black,
        factory = {
            val container = UIView()
            container.layer.addSublayer(cameraPreviewLayer)
            cameraPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            cameraPreviewLayer.frame = container.bounds
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT.toLong(), 0u)) {
                session.startRunning()
            }
            container
        },
        onResize = { container: UIView, rect: CValue<CGRect> ->
            CATransaction.begin()
            CATransaction.setValue(true, kCATransactionDisableActions)
            container.layer.setFrame(rect)
            cameraPreviewLayer.setFrame(rect)
            CATransaction.commit()
        })

    val delegate = object : NSObject(), AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegateProtocol {
        override fun captureOutput(
            output: AVCaptureOutput,
            didOutputSampleBuffer: CMSampleBufferRef?,
            fromConnection: AVCaptureConnection
        ) {
            didOutputSampleBuffer?.let { processSampleBuffer(it, onTextDetected) }
        }
    }

    videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(delegate, dispatch_get_main_queue())
}

private fun processSampleBuffer(
    sampleBuffer: CMSampleBufferRef,
    onTextDetected: (String) -> Unit
) {
    val pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

    if (pixelBuffer == null) {
        println("CameraPermissionManager || Pixel buffer is null")
        return
    }

    val handler = VNImageRequestHandler(pixelBuffer, options = mapOf<Any?, Any?>())

    val request = VNRecognizeTextRequest { request, error ->
        if (error != null) {
            println("CameraPermissionManager || Error recognizing text: $error")
            return@VNRecognizeTextRequest
        }

        val observations = request?.results?.filterIsInstance<VNRecognizedTextObservation>()

        observations?.forEach { observation ->
            val topCandidates = observation.topCandidates(1u)
            topCandidates.firstOrNull()?.let { candidate ->
                val recognizedText = candidate as? VNRecognizedText
                recognizedText?.string?.let { text ->
                    onTextDetected(text)
                } ?: run {
                    println("CameraPermissionManager || Recognized text is null")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        handler.performRequests(listOf(request), null)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("CameraPermissionManager || Error performing Vision request: $e")
    }
}

The Problem:
On iOS, the text detected by the camera (detectedText) is not reliably updating the UI elements like the FooterDetection and the milkCondition. However, I can see the correct values being logged, so the text is being detected properly. The issue seems to be related to how the UI state updates are handled, potentially due to threading.
Potential Cause:
I'm aware that on iOS, UI updates need to occur on the main thread. I've already wrapped the onTextDetected callback in dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) to ensure it's running on the main thread. Despite this, the UI updates are still inconsistent, and I'm unsure if there's something else I'm missing related to thread handling or Compose-specific behavior on iOS.
Question:
Has anyone else encountered similar issues with Compose Multiplatform on iOS? Is there something specific to Compose on iOS that I need to consider for ensuring consistent UI updates? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help!

there's a chance it happens because of recompositions - I would have tried moving all initialization code inside factory, and making sure onTextDetected is properly handled with rememberUpdatedState - see how it's done in BackHandler

thanks @PhilDukhov. I've tried as you suggested but nothing changed :-(
